# SQL- SELECT something AS with multiple where

Tags: mysql

I'd like to the output of SQL query to appear as below.

---

### |COUNT_A|COUNT_B|COUNT_C|COUNT_D|

|   2    |   3   |  4    |    5  |

The current output that I get using UNION ALL is

---

### |COUNT_A|

2 
3 
4 
5

```
SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_A from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM TEN_TO_INST_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%y%' AND AND INS_NAME not like 'x%y%z'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_B from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM T_IN_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%as%'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_C from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM T_IN_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%dfg%'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_D from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM T_IN_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%y%z'
```

Could I please ask someone's help here. I am not good at this please.

Comment: Please reduce your problem to the very core. You could at least format your queries properly.

Comment: Attempt to format your code and to describe the question.  If you won't put the time into make your question understandable to others, why should anyone else put time into answering it?

Comment: Hello - Thank you for responding. I didn't notice the code was unformatted. Usually the editor prompts me to format code which it didn't this time around. Apologies. Could you please take a look now?

Comment: Thank you to those who are working to answer the question. Highly appreciate your efforts.I managed to work out the answer. Refer to the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.COUNT_A, t2.COUNT_B,t3.COUNT_C,t4.COUNT_D FROM
(SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_A from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM TEN_TO_INST_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%y%' AND AND INS_NAME not like 'x%y%z') t1
,
(SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_B from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM T_IN_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%as%') t2
,
(SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_C from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM T_IN_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%dfg%') t3
,
(SELECT COUNT(INS_NAME) as COUNT_C from table_A where INS_NAME IN ( SELECT INS_NAME from table_B WHERE INS_ID IN (SELECT INS_MAP_ID FROM T_IN_MAP where T_IN_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TW WHERE TNAM = 'abc'))) AND T_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND INS_NAME NOT LIKE 'x%pr%' AND INS_NAME like 'x%y%z') t4
```